# git Modify historical submission records

Tags: git, shell

[image]

I want to achieve the following goals

1. Modify the email address. The email address for historical submissions is jiangyg@akulaku.com and the email address for historical submissions is candra@bankneo.co.id.
2. Increase the time range. I only want to modify records after the date 2021-12-22.

I tried this script, but it didn't achieve the specified time range filtering function

```bash
git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
OLD_EMAIL="candra@bankneo.co.id"
CORRECT_NAME="jiangyangang"
CORRECT_EMAIL="candra@bankneo.co.id"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL"] && [ `git show -s --format="%ct" $GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` -gt $(date -d "2021-12-22" +%s) ];
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]  && [ `git show -s --format="%ct" $GIT_COMMIT` -gt $(date -d "2021-12-22" +%s) ];
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Looking forward to your reply, thank you

Comment: Couldn't you use `.mailmap` instead to map old email addresses to the current ones? That sounds a lot simpler than rewriting all of the history and is non-destructive (which is another advantage)

Comment: Note that you could provide `--after` and `--since` as well to limit the filtering to only the commits that fall into the time range.

Comment: Where in the script should I add the --after and --since parameters?

 Using .mailmap is a good idea, but that's not what I want

Comment: `--after`/`--since` are rev-list options, which are supported by `filter-branch`, same as `--all` is a rev-list option too.